# Integrate PushWoosh on iOS

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, pushwoosh

I am trying to implement Push notifications on my iOS app using PushWoosh.  However, their tutorial...there's no nice way to say it.  Their tutorial is awful.  It just stinks.  It is simply the worst.  Here is the entire tutorial steps:

> 1. For the truly seamless integration all you have to do is to simply add Push NotificationsSDK to your project!
> 2. In your Info.plist add the following key Pushwoosh_APPID with your Pushwoosh Application ID string value
> 3. To handle push notifications add the following function to your App Delegate.m file

```
     #import "PushNotificationManager.h"

    - (void) onPushAccepted:(PushNotificationManager *)pushManager withNotification:(NSDictionary *)pushNotification {
         NSLog(@"Push notification received");
     }
```

> That’s it! Easy, isn’t it?

Wow, that was easy.  Except for a few minor things....it's an empty method!  There's nothing there inside the method.  No calls for how to register it with the service, nothing!  Does someone have some experience in what all needs to be coded to set this up properly?  Even their sample app has nothing in the App Delegate to reference this.

Comment: Have you tried it? It'd be pretty ballsy to write simple instructions like those and present them to the world if they didn't actually work. Note that there are quite a few other setup steps required -- it's just integrating the SDK that's simple. And if they have a sample app that appears to lack the configuration code that you seem to expect, doesn't it seem prudent to consider that such code really might not be needed?

Comment: Yes I tried it, no it didn't work.  I did every single step that they require on their set up page, and it doesn't work.  Why doesn't it work?  Because their code they list is just filler.  There is absolutely NOTHING in the code they list for AppDelegate.m that does anything other than fire an NSLog.

Comment: No, the code they list is what would be called when you **get** a push notification. Typically, you'd replace the `NSLog()` with your own code that does whatever you want to do when the notification is received. Presumably, since they don't call out a method that you're supposed to call at startup, the work needed to register for notifications is done by the framework's initialization code. Double check the build settings and confirm that you've not only added the framework to your project, but that your app actually links to it.

Comment: @Caleb I get the feeling you are not following me at all.  I answered my own question to show others trying to implement PushWoosh what was left out.  They USED to have this on their configuration page, but removed it for some reason.

Comment: Per shader's answer below the *some reason* is that the code is no longer needed.

Comment: Try This


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25182023/integrating-pushwoosh-on-ios-7-not-getting-subscribed-on-pushwoosh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what was left out.  In the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, you need to add:

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];
    pushManager = [[PushNotificationManager alloc] initWithApplicationCode:@"YOUR_APP_ID" appName:@"YOUR_APP_NAME"];
    pushManager.delegate = self;
    [pushManager handlePushReceived:launchOptions];
```

Then, you also need these methods in the AppDelegate.m

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)devToken
{
    [pushManager handlePushRegistration:devToken];
  }

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)pushMessage
{
    [pushManager handlePushReceived:pushMessage];
}
```

Comment: The SDK handles the registration and everything automatically using the powers of Objective-C runtime. You only need to pass -ObjC flag to the linker (this is VERY important step).

Comment: Followed all directions you had on site, didn't work.  Found an old video showing code that used to be on your site, @shader plugged it in and it worked.

Comment: @user717452 - you're 100% correct. Replaced     PushNotificationManager * pushManager = [PushNotificationManager pushManager];
 with your code, and boom, works perfectly. Before that, I was getting no registration. Quite disappointing on pushwooshs behalf to have code that doesn't work in their setup guide.

Answer (score 3):

The SDK handles the registration and everything automatically using the powers of Objective-C runtime. You only need to pass -ObjC flag to the linker (this is VERY important step).

It looks like the easiest way sometimes confuses developers more than "hard and painful".

Thank you for your feedback and we will provide better documentation!

Pushwoosh team

Comment: I had the -ObjC flag to the linker, and the SDK never registered the device.  I added in the code to the applicationDidFinish and it registered it right away.

Answer (score 1):

I just bumped into this recently myself and thought I'd add my results here. For myself at least, the reason that the linker flag was not working was that I had set it under the Project, instead of setting it on the Target. After switching it to the Target, it began to register the device as advertised.